# Как в питоне заменить одинарный слэш на двойной?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как заменить одинарный слэш на двойной? Попробовал этот метод, но что-то в итоге ничего не поменялось. Идея в том, чтобы не исправлять каждый раз вручную путь к файлам.

```
file_path=f"K:\Lib\Docs\Text\Modules".replace("'\'","\\")
```

Comment: `r"K:\Lib\Docs\Text\Modules"`

Comment: То что вы пытаетесь сделать работать не будет. Обратные слешы уже испорчены в исходной строке. Исправить их не получится. Весь вопрос построен на непонимании что такое литерал и чем отличается от строки в памяти. Используйте префикс `r` и не забивайте себе голову.

Answer (score 0):

обратный слэш есть символ экранирования следовательно умножаем его количество на два

````
''.replace('\\','\\\\')```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import platform

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        filename = 'D:/Python/abs.txt'
    else:
        filename = '/home/opendata/opendata/abs.txt'
    print(filename.replace("/", os.sep))
```